# Android activity forward result not working as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android application and I've got three activities A,B,C. activity A starts B, which may or may not start C. I want activity A to get results from either activity B or C.

If activity B never starts activity C I can successfully get data back to activity A by doing

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.PutExtra("DataId", item.Id);
SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
```

When the user wants to start activity C then I use this code to allow forwarding of the result from activity C back to activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityC));
intent.PutExtra("DataId", dataId);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ForwardResult);
StartActivity(intent);
```

If activity B starts activity C and then activity C wants to return data I do that with this code

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.PutExtra("DataId", dataId);
SetResult(Result.Ok, result);
Finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityA));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
StartActivity(intent);
```

This all works well. The problem occurs when activity C does not want to return data. If I call `Finish();` on activity C and then attempt to call `SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);` on activity B, those values from activity B are never returned to activity A. It's still using the empty data from activity C even though I never called 'SetResult();` on activity C.

Bottom line. How can I get activity B to return proper data, after starting activity C and returning back to activity B?

Comment: When you start Activity B and Activity C, are you using StartActivityForResult as outlined here? https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_activity_for_result/ I would think that if you start B from A with StartActivityForResult, and then start C from B with the same, when you get the result back from C in B then set the result from B so it goes back to A, I would think that should work. I don't see you using StartActivityForResult anywhere.

Comment: I did omit that code. Activity A starts activity B for result. That is why `SetResult()` works at all. Starting activity C for result and using `ActivityFlags.ForwardResult` throws an exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem occurs when activity C does not want to return data. If I call Finish(); on activity C and then attempt to call SetResult(Result.Ok, intent); on activity B, those values from activity B are never returned to activity A.

If you refer to [ForwardResult](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Content.ActivityFlags.ForwardResult/):

> If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transfered to the new activity.

So, from your description, you've forwarded the "reply target" from `ActivityB` to `ActivityC`. If you want to jump back from `ActivityC` to `ActivityB` and let `ActivityB` to call `SetResult`, you need to return the "reply target" back to `ActivityB` by adding `ActivityFlags.ForwardResult` again in `ActivityC`:

```
//click the button and go back to ActivityB without result
private void BtnBackBNoResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityB));
    intent.PutExtra("Information", "winffee");
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ForwardResult);
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This turned out to work just fine with 1 tweak. I didn't want a new instance of ActivityB so I just added `ActivityFlags.SingleTop`. Thanks a bunch! Seems so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in Xamarin the Application class as described [here:](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811464/Introduction-to-Xamarin-Android?msg=4996836#xx4996836xx)

**The Application Class**

If you need to maintain state across your application, then you will need an Application class. Although it is possible to pass information to / from Activity and Fragment classes, if you have a requirement to maintain global state (such as the currently logged in user name), then you achieve this using an Application class.

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public string CurrentUser = "";
}
```

Note that the class is decorated with the [Application] attribute. This is so that the necessary element is generated and added to the AndroidManifest.xml file. This ensures the class is instantiated when the application / package is created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:installLocation="auto" package="com.mydemo.apk" android:versionCode="1">
    <!--This line ensures the application class is instantiated automatically-->
    <application android:label="MyDemo" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

To use the Application class in your own code, you will also need to determine the current Context. In Android, the Context refers to the current state of the application / object. The Context class is also the base class for (but not limited to)

- Activity class
- Service class

There are several ways in which you can determine the application Context. One way is to add a method to your Application class definition that returns the Context as in the following code:

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public Context GetContext()
    {
        return ((this).ApplicationContext);
    }
}
```

Then in your application code, you can invoke it as follows.

```
MyApplication application = (MyApplication)GetContext();
String username = application.GetCurrentUser();
String password = application.GetPassword();
```

Comment: I'm aware I can save the information in an alternate place and retrieve it later, but I would like to find a solution that moves information between activities without the use of an application class. It seems to me like I've found a bug in android, unless someone knows of a solution.

Comment: the flag clear_top you use maybe is the problem: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
"For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B."